# Firebase account creation limit

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In [Firebase Authentication Limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits) it states that new account creation limit is     100 accounts/IP address/hour. I could not find any further explanation on this, i.e. what happens if the limit is exceeded, because it is very likely that there might be more than 100 new user creation after the launch of the app or a successful marketing campaign.

It states that "You can schedule a temporary increase to the account creation limit in the Firebase console."
Is that a paid service? How much does it cost? How long is temporary? How often can it be scheduled?

Answer (score 4):

To add to the Frank van Puffelen's answer, this is easily customizable via the Firebase console: Authentication tab -> Manage sign-up quota (at the very bottom) to get this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The IP limit is in place to protect your project against abuse. Setting a temporary increase is available to all Firebase projects, free or paid.

I don't think there is any documented limit to how often you can increase this, although that too is monitored for abuse.

Comment: Am I reading it correctly that 100 accounts, per IP, per hour. So we can get unlimited accounts to sign up to our project within an hour, providing they are from different IP addresses?

Comment: @sketchthat.  I think you're reading that right.  That number seems absurdly high.  For my use case, I'd like to limit it to 1 per day, but I'm assuming this doesn't allow fractional sign-ups so I wouldn't be able to achieve that.  Instead, I'll have to implement my own solution.  Bummer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding further to the answers. When deciding on the quota per IP per hour, it is worth noting that some users from the same organization may share an IP address. Therefore, depending on your use case, you may want to set the limit higher than would otherwise be the case. It is also possible to whitelist an IP so it is not limited.